# How to test file inputs with Cypress in last version of Chrome

Tags: file-upload, cypress, e2e-testing

Please help me. I want to upload file in my input-file.
My code is working fine in Chrome70 version. But after it stoped working. I am using this function.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', (fileName, fileType = ' ', selector) => {
return cy.get(selector).then(subject => {
    cy.fixture(fileName, 'base64')
        .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
        .then(blob => {
            const el = subject[0];
            const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, {
                type: fileType
            });
            const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
            dataTransfer.items.add(testFile);
            el.files = dataTransfer.files;
        });
});
```

});

And in test I writing

```
    const fileName = 'PNG.png';
    const fileType = 'aplication/png';
    const fileInput = '.editor-image-component .t-file-uploader-input';

    cy.uploadFile(fileName, fileType, fileInput);
```

But it not working now. And not working "cypress-file-upload" plugin too.
Can anyone help me.

Note: when I am trying to upload fake file (which one not in my fixture folder), I have a assertion error

Comment: please share some logs, screenshots with your failure

Comment: I have not any error, this is example using  plugin https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pe-4O8qzzchinrKCUphyFsy96usc6K_I/view But file is not shown in input field

Comment: could you check on the browser's developer tools for upload request on cypress run? I do remember Chrome(in case you use Chrome) was canceling requests to load things within frames or iframes, but in very specific situations

Comment: @NarinePoghosyan did you mange to solve this issue somehow? I've been struggling with the same issue for hours now. Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: not yet. "cypress-file-upload" plugin   working in my project with angular. But in Vue.js  project is not working yet.